# Knockout Array Checkbox not binding properly

Tags: knockout.js

I have an HTML input textbox and on its `change` event, I want my checkbox to be enabled if head count > user count for the id/row of that particular input box. Please help. Here is my HTML code:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: countryScopes.countryScopesData">
   <tr style="vertical-align: baseline">
      <td style="white-space:nowrap"><span data-bind="text: name" /></td>
      <td><span data-bind="text: level" style="text-align: left"/></td>
      <td><span data-bind="text: users"  style="text-align: center"/></td>
      <td>
         <input data-bind="textInput: lowHeadCount, event: { change: myAction }"  id="lowHeadCount" class="amount lowHeadCountClass"" style="text-align: center"  />
      </td>
      <td>                               
         <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" data-bind="click: enableCentralImp, checked: centralImpLowHeadCountFlag, enable: isAvailable && lowHeadCount"   />
      </td>                                
      <td>                                 
         <input data-bind="textInput: centralImpLowHeadCountpercent, enable: isAvailable && isPercentAvailable" class="amount lowHeadCountPercentClass" />% 
      </td>
      <td><span data-bind="text: Total.toFixed(2)" style="text-align: left"/></td>
      <td>$<span data-bind="text: Cost" style="text-align: left"/></td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Knockout function:

```
var Valuelowheadcount = this.lowHeadCount();
var countryId = this.id;
var HeadCountFlag = this.centralImpLowHeadCountFlag();
if (Valuelowheadcount > this.users) {
    this.isAvailable = true;
}
return true;
```

Comment: try  `this.isAvailable(true)` instead of `=` & also  `enable: isAvailable() && lowHeadCount()` .

Comment: it is working fine as per the above suggestion . Thanks

Comment: you want me to put up as a answer so u can mark it or feel free to post.